# ASP WebConfig Security Access Issues

Tags: asp.net, web-config

The below security section of my web config isn't behaving as I would expect.

What I would expect: default to accessible to everyone, any where else they try to go takes them redirect to the login, only this isn't happening, I'm not able to access any page.

If I remove everything but the authentication mode forms and the restriction to BankDetails, trying to access anything within there is blocked and takes you to redirect, however it's more secure to block everything and allow access to different parts with user roles I believe.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
     <!-- security stuff -->
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="~/Account/Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="~/Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="BankDetails">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

`When evaluating rules, ASP.NET scans through the list from top to bottom. As soon as it finds an applicable rule, it stops its search.`

With that in mind, you should change your rules to be like this:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx"/>
</authentication>
</system.web>
 <location path="~/Default.aspx">
 <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
<location path="~/Account/Login.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

There is no need to add one explicitly for BankDetails as it will be caught by the last rule `<deny users="?"/>`

**EDIT**
I added `<allow users="*"/>` to the final catch all

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still doesn't work, it's definitely something to do with the final authorization denial as it works if that's not there, just a lot cleaner if I can allow access to certain things rather than manually block almost everything.